# VLCKit for MAC OS X 10.7

Tags: gcc, osx-lion, vlc, xcode4.1

I have a problem with build VLCKit for MAC OS X 10.7.2
There is an error

```
--------------------------------------------------------
ld: library not found for -lvlccore
Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

and i already read this forum  https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&p=222191

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

- 1) `clang` isn't GCC.  That thread you pointed to above says VLC requires the GCC compiler.  However, that thread is also from 2009.
- 2) Why are you using Xcode 4.1?  You can get to Xcode 4.2 for free.
- And lastly, maybe you simply need to build (and install) the vlccore library before building VLCKit?